# Incorrect preview for link with closing parenthesis at the end

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

When I write a link whose URL ends with a closing parenthesis, it's handled correctly when I save the post, but not when I look at it in a preview.

For example [this markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521478/41071):

```
[`CSharpCompilation.ToMetadataReference()`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/2.0.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation/ToMetadataReference(System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray(System.String),System.Boolean)).
```

It renders correctly when saved:

> [image]

But not in preview (notice the `)` just before the period):

> [image]

There seem to be quite a few questions about URLs with closing parentheses here, but I didn't see exactly this one.